# Trying to collect data from multiple tables with logic aritmethics

Tags: oracle, logic

I am trying to collect data from multiple tables with logic aritmethics like: OR AND NOT UNION INTERSECT.
I have 3 tables called: Customers, Flights, Booking.

[image: Table1]

[image: Table 2-3]

My aim is to get all the passportno from the customers table which took a flight more than once.

Thnaks for helpers.

Comment: What kind of SQL queries have you tried yourself so far? - Can you post an example SQL queries?

Comment: Select _ from _ where and or intersect distinct thats all what ive used untill now.

Comment: Why are you not considering using joins instead of set arithmetic? Sounds like you could use group by on the first table to work out which users had more than one flight, and then join that to the other tables as appropriately in order to get the extra information relating to the passports/flights. Also, is this for an Oracle or for a MySQL database? You should make sure you select the correct tags for your database platform.

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by` and `having` clauses. The having limits those rows that are count>1

### Schema

```
create table bookings
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    passportno int not null,
    flightnumber int not null,
    `day` date not null,
    row varchar(10) not null,
    seat varchar(10) not null
);
insert bookings(passportno,flightnumber,`day`,row,seat) values (1,2,'2005-01-01',1,1); -- Joe
insert bookings(passportno,flightnumber,`day`,row,seat) values (1,3,'2005-02-01',1,1); -- Joe
insert bookings(passportno,flightnumber,`day`,row,seat) values (2,3,'2005-02-01',2,2); -- Sally


create table customers
(
    passportno int primary key,
    name varchar(100) not null,
    address varchar(100) not null,
    phone varchar(20) not null
);
insert customers(passportno,name,address,phone) values (1,'Joe','addr','ph');
insert customers(passportno,name,address,phone) values (2,'Sally','addr','ph');
```

### Query and results

```
select c.passportno
from customers c 
join bookings b 
on c.passportno=b.passportno 
group by c.passportno 
having count(b.id)>1;

+------------+
| passportno |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
```

Mysql manual page entitled [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: Im using oracle database type. And as i mentioned before i mustnt use join command. Only actions about teams.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question the query should be something like

```
SELECT c.PASSPORTNO
  FROM CUSTOMERS c
  WHERE c.PASSPORTNO IN (SELECT DISTINCT PASSPORTNO
                           FROM (SELECT PASSPORTNO, FLIGHTNUMBER, COUNT(*)
                                   FROM BOOKINGS
                                   GROUP BY PASSPORTNO, FLIGHTNUMBER
                                   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Best of luck.